Wrong result of FourierTransform function
I try to calculate the Fourier transform of an expression using two different methods.
The first method is FourierTransform function
Simplify[FourierTransform[Exp[I π/(z λ) (x^2 + y^2)], {x, y}, {ξ, η}, 
  FourierParameters -> {1, -1}], z > 0 && λ > 0]
(* -I E^((I z λ (η^2 + ξ^2))/(4 π)) z λ *)


The second method is by manual integration
Simplify[FourierTransform[Exp[I π/(z λ) (x^2 + y^2)], {x, y}, {ξ, η}, 
  FourierParameters -> {1, -1}], z > 0 && λ > 0]
Integrate[Exp[I π/(z λ) (x^2 + y^2)] Exp[-I ξ x], x]
Integrate[% Exp[-I η y], y]
(* ... *)


Two methods return two different result. The biggest difference is the sign of the index. The second result is negative, and it is right. The FourierTransform function get the wrong result.
I have left a message on the Wolfram website. And the reply is as below:

If you go to the Wikipedia article on FourierTransforms:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Other_conventions
In the notes you will find an explanation of what is bothering you in the notes. The easiest way is to work with your examples is to use ExpToTrig on your results. You will then be able to see this is just a translation to put zero values at a particular location. I have attached a screenshtot from the Wikipedia article notes that specifically. addresses the issue that exists with Wolfram|Alpha.


The following is my qustion:

I can't understand the reply well. Could anyone explain it in detail?
How to set the parameters of FourierTransform to get the right answer?


If you have assumptions on the parameters, please use Assuming before the calculation:
Assuming[z > 0 && \[Lambda] > 0, 
 FourierTransform[
  Exp[I \[Pi]/(z \[Lambda]) (x^2 + y^2)], {x, y}, {\[Xi], \[Eta]}, 
  FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]]

(*I E^(-((I z \[Lambda] (\[Eta]^2 + \[Xi]^2))/(4 \[Pi]))) z \[Lambda]*)

Assuming[z > 0 && \[Lambda] > 0, 
 InverseFourierTransform[%, {\[Xi], \[Eta]}, {x, y}, 
  FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]]

(*E^((I \[Pi] (x^2 + y^2))/(z \[Lambda]))*)

